# Is it possible for a commonJS module to block until it exports?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, commonjs

I understand CommonJS modules actually block as they load.

In some cases I wish to do particular work - loading and parsing config files for my app server - in a blocking way, i.e, since the app isn't usable until those files have loaded, only export once those async operations are complete.

**Can I delay exporting until after an async operation in CommonJS?** Or should I just use sync file reading / parsing methods instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a function with a callback as parameter:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function parseContent(content) {
    // do the content parsing
}

exports.getFileData = function (callback) {
    fs.readFile('path/to/file', function (error, content) {
        var data;

        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            data = parseContent(content);
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};
```

usage:

```
moduleName.getFileData(function (data) {
    // process data
});
```

Comment: Yep, doing that now. However I'd like to quite specifically block in this case, eg, whatever loads this module should not continue whatsoever until the data is fetched. Knowing about the blocking nature of CommonJS made me think such a thing might exist, but maybe it doesn't and I should just use sync methods.

Comment: then it's the correct way to do this, there is no way to "delay", sure you can do it synchronously but this is not a desired way